# How to connect wired network to wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, wired

I have a wired network and my neigbhors offered to share wireless internet.  How do I connect my ethernet networks to wireless.  I don't understand There is ethernet port, wire and where d o I plugin other wire? Because wirless has no port, it's wireless, how is this even possible?

Ok so then We go to the beach and there is wireless there and we don't use wire to connect there, but to connect my wired network to wireless network how can I does?

Answer (score 1):

To link your wired network to your neighbour's wireless, you will need to connect a **Wireless Bridge** to your network and associate it with their wireless access point - or do something less ideal like drill a hole in the wall and connect a network cable to their equipment, if they have any spare data ports - even then, this idea is only really possible if you live right next door with only an internal wall between the two of you.

There's a few other ways it can be done, but a wireless bridge is probably the simplest - any decent computer supplier will stock these.

Comment: what bridge you recommends? neatgear, linksys, do you know price?

Comment: Most of the consumer-grade wireless bridges behave in very similar ways and so prices are close too. The main difference will be whether you want a bridge with a single data port (to connect to your network), or multiple ports, a built in print server etc. I would see what your favourite supplier has in stock.

Answer (score 0):

You need a wireless bridge or a wireless gaming adapter, which is a device that connects to a wireless network and provides one or more wired Ethernet ports.  These devices are often used to connect gaming consoles and other devices to a wireless network when the devices themselves don't have wi-fi connectivity, hence they are sometimes called gaming adapters.

Comment: thank you mah frienz appreciate your times in assistence, hope i can do same to you